# Use different SSH keys with GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, ssh, github-desktop

i was using sourcetree (since it is not launching on windows AGAIN I am skiping it forever :) ) and there were no problems to provide different .ppk keys by adding them to Pageant. I am missing same functionality in GitHub desktop. It only works when i have one key in .ssh folder called id_rsa.
Is there any way to specify different ssh's because i have different github accounts for different projects.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if GitHub Desktop has UI for this but to specify default ssh key you need to add

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyhello
```

in In your ~/.ssh/config file.

Comment: GitHub Desktop was the question though.